# Offer free in-app purchase to exsisting users

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I made an app which is now live inside Google Play Store (it was also inside Apple App Store until Apple removed it without a reason). The app costs 1.99 but I'm now thinking about adding ads and set it as free (I'm not sure anyway..) with in-app purchase to remove ads.

The problem is I absolutely don't want to make people pay again (I'm talking about who already purchased it). How can I offer free in-app to existing users? I don't have an online db of users, the app is totally offline.

Comment: Well, how do you plan on removing ads on an app if you don't know who is using it? You gotta have that information stored somewhere. Maybe an update to the app, where it's users (since now its paid) once login, they will not receive ads and send their registration information to your secure db. Then, you store it local on each app, if the user can or cannot have ads based on what you want.

Comment: Ok I can save such an info inside user device with an update and then, with the update with ads, automatically remove advertising if there is this flag saved.. The problem is: should I do it programmatically or can I let the user purchase the in-app for free? Because I'm thinking about "restore purchase".. If I remove the ads programmatically, if the user changes the device must pay again.. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am enhancing the [Abr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2515350/abr) comment.

First, whenever you dealing such situation you must have server DB (for auth) and  to store who have purchased your app . I don't think you need local DB but you need a flag which defines whther the current user purchased the app or not and you can maintain the flag in `NSUserDefault` .

Now, Whenever user logins in by any device you need to match his **email ID/Phone no** in your server DB through API and check whether his user credentials are valid or not and if it is valid then it is purchased user or not and save this flag in `NSUserDefault`.

Now do whatever you wanted to change in your app it does not reflect any issue to your purchased user because they always be filtered from the server.

**NOTE :** You didn't consider one condition, what if one user is signup in your app through android app and make google in-app purchase. Later he buy iPhone and downloads your app from apple store. According to your current scenario he have to purchase your app for i-phone also. I dont think one user wanted to purchase it again.

So my explanation will resolve this issue also.

> Edit
>
> As you said app is completely offline in comment.

To make in-app purchase transaction you make to user to come online. Now you can do one thing, during this time if user payment is successful then store its data into server (obviously he purchased app by any ID so store that ID).

Now when user again install give a **restore** option in in-app screen. When user clicks on this button check the user state whether the user is paid or not in your server DB and here ask user for email.

And if you don't have server DB then restore the transaction from native store.

Comment: The problem is the app is without registration.. is completely offline

Comment: ^this seems the best practical solution in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your current App with "NameApp Pro", let it at 1.99.

With Android flavors create a new App Free with Ads. With flavors you can change the applicationId (package are differents) :

[Set the Application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationIdSuffix ".free"
        }
        pro {
            applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
        }
    }
}
```